# Redirect every URL to other domain homepage

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got an old domain that I want to redirect every single page to MYNEWDOMAIN.COM, without anything after .COM

I was trying to do something with .htaccess, but I've just redirected everything to the index.html and then to MYNEWDOMAIN.COM.

```
-- .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [R=302]

-- index.html
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=http://www.mynewdomain.com">
```

Is there anything I can do better?

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule on top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.*) https://mynewdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works but the new URL will have "index.php? [...]", is it possibile to clean everything?